# Serial data parsing

Tags: c, serial-port

I have a probably simple question, which I just cant seem to understand.

I am creating a serial parser for a datalogger which sends a serial stream. Under the documentation for the product a calculation is stated, which I don't understand.

```
Lateral = Data1 And 0x7F + Data2 / 0x100
If (Data1 And 0x80)=0 Then Lateral = -Lateral
```

What does `Data1` And `0x7f` means? I know that `7F` is `127`, but besides that I don't understand the combination with the And statement.

What would the real formula look like?

Comment: It is a bitwise-and to ensure the top bit in the octet is *clear* for that part of the expression. For what its worth the logic for the second line doesn't exactly appear right if the purpose is to honor a sign-bit in the 8bit slot of Data1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise AND -- a bit in the output is set if and only if the corresponding bit is set in *both* inputs.

Since your tags indicate that you're working in C, you can perform bitwise AND with the & operator.

(Note that 0x7F is 01111111 and 0x80 is 10000000 in binary, so ANDing with these correspond respectively to extracting the lower seven bits and extracting the upper bit of a byte.)

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answers, I have just read a bit regarding the bitwise AND, and that makes sence to me. Is the "Data1" just signed a 1(true) if it has data or how should that be understood?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1st sentence
`Lateral = Data1 And(&) 0x7f + Data2/ 0x100`

means take the magnitude of `Data1`(Data and 0x7f) and add to it the value of `Data2/256`

2nd sentence
check the sign od `Data1` and assign the same to `Lateral`.